# Chain Rule, need clarification on how to use it correctly for $e^{2t \sin 2t}$?

Tags: calculus

I was working on this problem where I need to use the chain rule: $e^{2t \sin 2t}$. I thought I was understanding how to solve these until I cam to this problem which appears to be subtly more complex than other examples where we just chained 2 or 3 functions together. I thought this was the chain of 3 functions:

Let $y = e^u$, $u = 2t\sin v$, $v = 2t$

So I tried solving by saying:

${dy\over dt} = {dy\over du} {du\over dv} {dv\over dt}$

I ended up with ${dy\over du} = e^u$, ${du\over dv} = (2t)(\sin v)' + (\sin v)(2t)'$, and ${dv\over dt} = 2$

Chaining them together (and adding the equations for the substitutions) results in:

${dy\over du} = (e^{2t\sin v})((2t)(\sin v)'+(\sin v)(2t)')(2)$

Since I was left with the unfinished $(\sin v)'$ term in the "middle" function, I used the chain rule yet again since $v = 2t$, and thus $(\sin v)' = f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)$, where $f'(g(x) = \cos(2t)$ and $g'(x) = 2$, so I get putting all this together:

${dy\over du} = (e^{2t\sin v})((2t)(\cos(2t)(2))+(\sin(2t))(2))(2)$

**But then I learn that that last part "$(2)$" at the end of the equation is incorrect** (note I don't need to simplify right now as I'm just learning how to use the chain rule).

---

This then leads me to think that this function must not be the chain of three functions together in succession (i.e. ${dy\over dt} = {dy\over du} {du\over dv} {dv\over dt}$). Instead, the correct way appears to involve two separate chain-rule usages:

1. $f(x) = e^{g(x)} \implies f(g(x)) = e^x$, where $g(x) = 2t \sin x$ as one group of functions where the chain rule will be applied. This will get us to: $f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x) = (e^{2t \sin v})((2t)(\sin(h(x)))'+(\sin(h(x))(2t)')$
2. At the moment we get to $(\sin(h(x)))'$ we need to once again apply the chain-rule, concretely a sperate implementation of the rule not part of first chain-rule usage. So in this case the chain rule would be applied to $i(x) = \sin(h(x)) \implies i(h(x)) = \sin(x) $. And so to solve he have $i'(h(x)) \cdot h'(x)) = \cos(2t) \dot 2$

---

So my question then is, do I understand this problem right? That it is not a chain of three functions, but rather the product rule flanked with separate usages of the chain rule (one before we get the product rule, and the other for a term that we come to when applying the product rule).

For some reason I find this a bit hard to wrap my mind around it, so I really am looking for a clearer explanation of what is going on here. I'm also not 100% sure they my understanding of what is happening is correct.

Comment: Your mistake is in taking $u=2t \sin(v)$, $v = 2t$. The variables $v,t$ are not independent of each other, so everything you do with $u$ from that point on is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to differentiate $e^{f(t)}$. Using the chain rule, we get $$\frac{d}{dt} e^{f(t)} = e^{f(t)} \cdot f'(t),$$ where $f(t) =2t \sin (2t)$. Differentiating $f(t)$ we get $$\begin{align}f'(t) & = \left( \frac{d}{dt} (2t) \right) \sin(2t) + 2t \cdot \frac{d}{dt} (\sin(2t)) \\ & = 2 \sin(2t) + 2t \cdot \cos(2t) \cdot 2 \\ & = 2 \sin(2t) + 4t \cos(2t). \end{align}$$ Your mistake is that your extra $2$ is coming from differentiating $2t$ inside $\sin(2t)$. You're not differentiating it, therefore there's no extra $2$.

Comment: That makes sense, and just to be sure when you write: $(\sin(2t))'$ that you also apply the chain rule to get $\cos(2t)2$, right?

Comment: Yes. I skipped a step. What happens is $$\frac{d}{dt} \sin(2t) = \frac{d}{du} \sin (u) \frac{d}{dt} (2t) = \cos (u) \cdot 2 = \cos(2t) \cdot 2,$$ where $u=2t$.

Comment: So I should only apply the chain rule when I cannot differentiate a function by other means (like using the product rule). Using the product rule in this case in essence breaks the existing chain, even though a new chain later in the process is required. Is this correct?

Comment: You apply the chain rule when you have composition of functions. You need to see that there's a composition.